# How do I fix "Failed to unmount /oldroot..." errors when shutting down?

Tags: shutdown

How do I fix "Failed to unmount /oldroot..." errors when shutting down?

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 latest updates. My boot partition is formatted "W95 FAT32 (Bootable)" in case this has anything to do with the problem.

```
Failed to unmount /oldroot: Device or resource busy
Failed to unmount /oldroot/dev/pts: Device or resource busy
Failed to unmount /oldroot/dev: Device or resource busy
Failed to finalize file systems, ignoring
```

Despite these errors, my computer seems to shut off and reboot fine every time. But I would like to clean up whatever is causing these errors.

I've already done sudo apt update, sudo apt upgrade, and sudo apt --purge autoremove, but these errors persist.

Thank you!